# How do I rerun the editor after the git commit-msg hook?

Tags: git

I have a git commit-msg hook that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE="$1"
COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(cat "$COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE")

if echo $COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep -q "PROJ-XXXX"
then
    echo "ERROR: Please either delete the PROJ-XXXX, or enter a proper JIRA ticket number"
    exit 1
fi
```

This works, but if I write a commit message during a commit, and forget to update the ticket number, it will close the editor, show the error, and discard my message completely.

Is there a way to have the hook either rerun the editor so I can edit my message, or at least remember what my commit message was next time I run `git commit -v` so I don't need to retype the commit message?

Comment: If nothing else better comes up, you can always do `echo $COMMIT_MESSAGE >some_file` in the `then` block.  Then `git commit -m "$(cat some_file)"`.

Comment: Why are you reading the entire file into memory instead of just using `grep -q "PROJ-XXX" "$1"`?

Comment: @chepner that works too. It would probably matter more if modern computers didn't have gigabytes of memory (my laptop has 32GB), and git commit messages weren't inherently tiny, but I know what you mean. It's mostly because `COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE` and `COMMIT_MESSAGE` are more clear then `$1` . That and muscle memory. I'm used to piping things to grep instead of having grep read it, which is probably bad in some situations. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I thought there might be a simple, built-in way to do it, but I guess not.
I just wrote this - it seems to work pretty good:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# JIRA tag format
JIRA_TAG="PROJ-XXXX"

# Allows us to read user input below, assigns stdin to keyboard
exec < /dev/tty

# Colors
SWITCH="\033["
NORMAL="${SWITCH}0m"
RED="${SWITCH}1;31m"
YELLOW="${SWITCH}1;33m"

# Commit file
COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE="$1"

while true
do
    COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(cat "$COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE")

    if echo $COMMIT_MESSAGE | grep -q "${JIRA_TAG}"
    then
        # Print the problem
        echo -e "${RED}ERROR${NORMAL}: Please either delete the ${YELLOW}${JIRA_TAG}${NORMAL}, or enter a proper JIRA ticket number"
        read -p "Press Enter to Try Again"

        # Rerun in editor
        # Exit if editor exits with an error
        # This lets someone break out of loop with :cq in vim
        # Nano doesn't appear to have a similar way to exit with an error
        # code
        $EDITOR "$COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE" || exit 1
    else
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

This git hook, saved in `.git/hooks/commit-msg`, along with a `~/.gitmessage` of something like this:

```sh
Jira Tickets: PROJ-XXXX
```

Ensures that you never forget to include a JIRA tag in your commit.

Note: `~/.gitmessage` needs to be enabled with something like:

`git config --global commit.template ~/.gitmessage`

and the `commit-msg` hook needs to be executable (`chmod +x .git/hooks/commit-msg`)